# Reading numeric as Text, tshow and show in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read an integer to Text:

```
-- This works
mm x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as Text"
        T.putStrLn x
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm "10"
```

Produces

```
Testing x being input as Text
10
```

Great.  If it starts as Text, this works.  This is fine.

But

```
-- This does not work
mm2 x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
        let m = tshow x
        T.putStrLn m
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm2 10

<interactive>:3:17: error:
    • Variable not in scope: tshow :: p -> t
    • Perhaps you meant ‘show’ (imported from Prelude)
```

I understand from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/basic-prelude-0.7.0/docs/BasicPrelude.html#v:tshow) that `tshow`:

```
tshow :: Show a => a -> Text
```

should exist in `Prelude` and should turn this a into Text.

Non-t, regular-`show` also fails:

```
-- This does not work
mm2 x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
        let m = show x
        T.putStrLn m
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm2 10
```

with

```
<interactive>:4:20: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘String’ with ‘Text’
      Expected type: Text
        Actual type: String
    • In the first argument of ‘Data.Text.IO.putStrLn’, namely ‘m’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: Data.Text.IO.putStrLn m
      In the expression:
        do Data.Text.IO.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
           let m = show x
           Data.Text.IO.putStrLn m
```

And so does

```
-- This does not work
mm2 x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
        let m = T.pack x
        T.putStrLn m
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm2 10
```

with

```
<interactive>:1:5: error:
    • No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal ‘10’
    • In the first argument of ‘mm2’, namely ‘10’
      In the expression: mm2 10
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = mm2 10
```

How can I read/show/pack/cast an integer as Text?  What am I doing wrong that this is difficult?

### Update 1

And also

```
-- This does not work
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text as TS
mm2 x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
        let m = T.tshow x
        T.putStrLn m
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm2 10
```

Produces

```
<interactive>:3:17: error:
    Not in scope: ‘T.tshow’
    No module named ‘T’ is imported.
```

### Update 2

And

```
mm2 x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
        let m = TS.tshow x
        T.putStrLn m
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm2 10
```

produces

```
<interactive>:3:17: error:
    Not in scope: ‘TS.tshow’
    No module named ‘TS’ is imported.
```

Comment: The link your providing is for `BasicPrelude` which some alternate prelude.  You’ll have to import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still unclear to me where `tshow` is and why it appears on Hoogle, but cannot be imported from `Prelude`, `Data.Text` or `Data.Text.IO`.

But this executes without error:

```
mm2 x = do 
        T.putStrLn "Testing x being input as an integer and converted to Text"
        let m = T.pack $ show x
        T.putStrLn m
        -- y <- x * 2
        -- putStrLn y

mm2 10
```

First `show` from `Prelude` to go from `Integer -> String` then `T.pack` to go from `String -> Text`.

Comment: "It is still unclear to me where tshow is and why it appears on Hoogle, but cannot be imported from Prelude, Data.Text or Data.Text.IO." I'm not sure why this is unclear. Hoogle is just a search engine for all publicly available Haskell modules/packages, including 3rd-party ones. The search for [tshow](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=tshow&scope=set%3Astackage) has plenty of hits but if you look at the package names you will see none are base packages. But [pack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:pack) is in the standard library's `Text` module.

Comment: Thanks. The confusion is that basicprelude turns out not to be the basic prelude, but is in fact a non basic, alternative prelude. I understand this is self evident to you, but for someone learning, and navigating the jungle of conflicting string libraries required to do even basic tasks, this was yet another surprise.

Comment: "I understand this is self evident to you" - far from it, and apologies if I came off as condescending. I'm very much still learning Haskell, have never done anything much in the way of "practical" programs in it, and barely know my way around large parts of even the standard library, let alone all the thousands of packages on Hackage. But perhaps that's why I know a bit better which libraries are included with GHC and which aren't :)